# Published angular4 aspnet core application not recognizing api end points

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have a published angular application which gives me a "Cannot match any routes" error everytime I try to access some api resources.

My base is set to `<base href="/">` and my api source is set to `api/user/info`.
The weird thing is, that it works perfectly fine when I'm running directly off IIS Express.

```
[Route("api/user")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("info", Name = "user_info")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Info()
    {
        var user = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;
        return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(Json(new
        {
            username = user.Name,
            authentication = user.AuthenticationType,
            groups = user.Groups?.Select(g => g.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value)
        }));
    }
}
```

Anyone have any clues as to why angular is trying to catch my api route?

EDIT: For Context
I also have anonymous authentication disabled as I'm trying to return information from the user principal as a windows identity (WindowsAuthentication).

Comment: Is it published inside a virtual directory?

Comment: nope, i have the directory setup as an application in IIS. i published using the dotnet cli `dotnet publish -c Debug`

Comment: Are you able to access the APIs successfully by typing the URL in a browser's address bar or via a tool like Postman?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/231

Turns out it was a bug the entire time. Accessing the AuthenticationType property throws an exception